# chrome.serial not available in Chrome packaged application

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, serial-port, arduino

I'm building a Chrome packaged application with an Arduino serial connection. Similar to what was demonstrated in the latest [Google I/O](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_I/O), *[The Next Evolution of Chrome Apps](https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/gooio2012/200/)* by Erik Kay, and Mihai Parparita.

I'm using the latest [Canary build](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome#Release_channels_and_updates) (23.0.1254.0) on [OS X 10.8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X_Mountain_Lion) (Mountain Lion).

However, the 'chrome' object is missing the 'serial' member.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'serial' permission is missing from the manifest.json :

```
  "permissions": ["serial"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I've successfully connected to serial from a packaged plugin designed to work with arduino however for compilation of code requires a server.

Then Chrome plugin is here:

https://github.com/DecodedCo/ArduinoInTheBrowser